# Invalid Use of Null Access List Box

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I am trying to calculate the sum of the values I select from a column of a Multiselect List Box and put it into textbox of a form. I have tried the piece of code shown below but I get the error 'Invalid Use of Null'

```
Private Sub SelectTreatment_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim sumduration As Integer
sumduration = 0

For i = 0 To Me.SelectTreatment.ListCount - 1

    If Me.SelectTreatment.ItemsSelected(i) Then
         sumduration = sumduration + Me.SelectTreatment.Column(4, i)
    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code or a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your code just a little bit. This should do the trick. Just make sure you have numeric values in the 5th column (index number 4).

```
Private Sub SelectTreatment_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sumduration As Integer
sumduration = 0
Dim frm As Form, ctl As Control, varItm As Variant

    Set frm = Forms!YourFormName
    Set ctl = frm!SelectTreatment
    For Each varItm In ctl.ItemsSelected
        sumduration = sumduration + ctl.Column(4, varItm)
    Next varItm
    Debug.Print sumduration
End Sub
```

Comment: This list box only as 4 columns in it...The same error has still come up and I think that's why but I have found that varItm is working as the value is changing when I select different items